# How to use Python Mock to raise an exception - but with Errno set to a given value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Given this Python code:

```
elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    try:
        os.remove(full_file)
        return jsonify({'results':'purged %s' % full_file})

    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
            raise

        return jsonify({'results':'file not present: %s' % full_file})
```

I want to test all possible paths, including the exception handling. Using Mock, it's easy enough to *raise* an exception, which I do with this code:

```
with patch('os.remove', new=Mock(side_effect=OSError(errno.ENOENT))):
    self.assertRaises(OSError, self.app.delete, file_URL) # broken
```

Mock raises an exception, which has a printed value of 2 (ENOENT) - but *e.errno* is set to NONE. And so far, I have not found a way to set it. The result is, the exception always gets *re-raised*, and I never reach the last line of code, in my unit test.

I've also tried creating a dummy class with errno set, and returning that. But unless it has *side_effect* set to be called, it doesn't raise an exception, and when I set side_effect, I don't get the object.errno as a return value.

Is there a way to have Mock raise an Exception, where that Exception object has the *errno* attribute set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass two arguments to OSError constructor. (First one should be `errno`).

For example:

```
>>> OSError(2).errno
>>> OSError(2, 'message').errno
2
>>> OSError(2, 'message').strerror
'message'
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast - and correct. :) Was this somewhere in Python's Exception docs? I did read those, but may have missed something.

Comment: @JohnC, I raised OSError intentionally and checked `args` attribute of the exception object.

Comment: Interesting - how did you determine that one of the `args` was `errno`? I'm looking at it, it just seems to be a tuple.

Comment: @JohnC, `args` is a tuple of arguments passed to the exception constructor.

Comment: @JohnC, See [`args` from exceptions module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException.args)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at OSError, and should have followed it up to [EnvironmentError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError), where they explain `errno` in more detail. Thanks, this was a learning experience.